# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq Nearby Place App

Tags: java, android

I made a app find nearby place but i get this error

```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/vapelit.unikomapps.com.vapelitfinal-1/base.apk"
```

Here my gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
```

}## Heading ##

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Agam

In your gradle code your are using google map library with different version. So remove old version library and make sure you are using same version of all google play service library which are related to each other.

Try to update below line in your gradle file and remove google play service library which include all google play services file under one gradle library. For mode details about google play service visit on [Google Play Service Version with Table 1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

```
implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

I hope you will resolve your problem.

Comment: @Agam Welcome. Let me know if any help required. Is this method help you to resolve your problem or Not?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement this :

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'


   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

and add this in your gradle :

```
 configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '28.0.0'
        }
     }
 }
}
```

and in your gradle you have to delete this :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
```

and keep only this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: it says Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.0

Comment: @Agam delete com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.0 I edit the ansewer

Comment: Thanks U so much Sir !! i appreciate your help ^^